# Alternative for s3Object = s3Client.getObject(bucketName, pathInS3) in amazonaws sdk v2

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services

```
S3Client s3Client; //autowired

s3Object = s3Client.getObject(bucketName, pathInS3);
```

Whats the alternative in amazonaws sdk v2?

GPT says,

```
responseInputStreamForS3Object = s3Client.getObject(GetObjectRequest.builder().key(pathInS3).bucket(bucketName).build());
```

Looks like : `key(pathInS3)`

.i.e

Key is same as path.

Not sure as, every doc on AWS says, `key =/= path`, though they look alike.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not that clear. I beleive you are asking about how to get objects from an S3 bucket.

WHen you want to get an object, specify the key name and bucket name. This is how you get a specific object. If you look at the Javadocs:

https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3Client.html

You will see that **getObject()** requires a **GetObjectRequest** object where you specify the key name and the bucket name.

For example, if you want to get a PDF named **book.pdf** and the bucket name is **bucketfoo**, you would create a **GetObjectRequest**  object.

```
GetObjectRequest objectRequest = GetObjectRequest
                    .builder()
                    .key("book.pdf")
                    .bucket("bucketfoo")
                    .build();
```

Also there are different **getObject** methods. For example, assume you want to get that PDF as a byte[] (and do something with that byte[]). In this case, you can use **getObjectAsBytes()**.

```
public static void getObjectBytes(S3Client s3) {
        try {
           GetObjectRequest objectRequest = GetObjectRequest
                    .builder()
                    .key("book.pdf")
                    .bucket("bucketfoo")
                    .build();

            ResponseBytes<GetObjectResponse> objectBytes = s3.getObjectAsBytes(objectRequest);
            byte[] data = objectBytes.asByteArray();

            // you can use data to meet your business requirements. 
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
```